# EMGU 2.4.0 BruteForceMatcher KNNMATCH not working?

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencv, emgucv

Here is a snapshot of my code,

```
Matrix<byte> mask;
int k = 2;
VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
SURFDetector surfCPU = new SURFDetector(500, false);
modelKeyPoints = surfCPU.DetectKeyPointsRaw(modelImage, null);
Matrix<float> modelDescriptors = surfCPU.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(modelImage, null, modelKeyPoints);
observedKeyPoints = surfCPU.DetectKeyPointsRaw(observedImage, null);
Matrix<float> observedDescriptors = surfCPU.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(observedImage, null, observedKeyPoints);
BruteForceMatcher<float> matcher = new BruteForceMatcher<float>(DistanceType.L2);
matcher.Add(modelDescriptors);
indices = new Matrix<int>(observedDescriptors.Rows, k);
using (Matrix<float> dist = new Matrix<float>(observedDescriptors.Rows, k))
{
      matcher.KnnMatch(observedDescriptors, indices, dist, k, null);
}
```

I always get the following exception at KnnMatch()

**Emgu.CV.Util.CvException occurred
Message: OpenCV: queryDescriptors.type() == trainDescCollection[0].type()**

I have tried so hard to get rid of this exception and no hope :(

Comment: I am too stuck on this problem. It will be nice if you can share anything that came out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause of this problem

it was one of  modelKeyPoints or observedKeyPoints null :)

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Zaher's answer - my modelKeyPoints was not null, but it was empty (modelKeyPoints.Size == 0).

Using a different model image helped.